# My powershell crashes on startup

Tags: windows-10, powershell

I'm having problem with my powershell.

It drops following log when started

```
Unhandled Exception: System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'System.Management.Automation.TypeAccelerators' threw an exception. ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.SEHException: External component has thrown an exception.
   at System.Management.Automation.CoreTypes.<>c.<.cctor>b__2_0()
   at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()
   at System.Lazy`1.LazyInitValue()
   at System.Management.Automation.TypeAccelerators..cctor()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.EarlyStartup.<>c.<Init>b__0_1()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(Task& currentTaskSlot)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteEntry(Boolean bPreventDoubleExecution)
   at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
```

Any help? I'm having Windows 10

Comment: This question should include more details and clarify the problem.  Please edit your question to provided those necessary details

Answer (score 0):

Check your powershell profile script, and clear out any offending commands or problems. The script is run when you start powershell.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_profiles?view=powershell-7#long-description

Comment: According to the TSHOOT already done on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62776824/11942268), it has nothing to do with profile scripts.